# Uploadify not showing progress on Firefox Mac

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, uploadify, m

my long and enduring website is almost completed.  While reviewing some testing I've noticed that my uploadify is working fine on all browsers except for firefox, and this is only happening on firefox which is on a MAC machine.  It is very odd, but the files are actually uploading fine, its just that the loading pregress bar % does not increase and stays at 0 until the script is actually completed.  Please hellllpppp.  Code is the same for all browsers and it is even working in IE 8.  Very odd,  Ive tried on all browsers, pc and mac.

UPDATE:

Im still painstakingly trying to get this to work.  I have used the onUploadProgress callback function

```
'onUploadProgress' : function(file, bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesTotal) {
                if(bytesUploaded > 10){
                    var test = "";
                }
                $('#progress').html(totalBytesUploaded + ' bytes uploaded of ' + totalBytesTotal + ' bytes.');
             }
```

and I try to see if it is called.  I can never get it to call within the debugger beyond bytesUploaded = 0 .  For some reason the onUploadProgress is not initiating during this progress.  The file uploads fine but it isn't showing the progress which is an issue for the user.

Ive also tried to dig into the inner workings of the uploadify.js file to find out where it does its uploading process and the same thing occurs.  Below is the code where this takes place.

```
function g(x,C,z){
                                                                                    var v=new Date();
                                                                                    var D=v.getTime();
                                                                                    var A=D-j.timer;
                                                                                    j.timer=D;
                                                                                    var y=C-j.bytesLoaded;
                                                                                    j.bytesLoaded=C;
                                                                                    var u=j.queue.queueBytesUploaded+C;
                                                                                    if(C > 100){
                                                                                        var TEST = "";
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    var F=Math.round(C/z*100);
                                                                                    var B=0;var w=(y/1024)/(A/1000);
                                                                                    w=Math.floor(w*10)/10;
                                                                                    if(j.queue.averageSpeed>0){
                                                                                        j.queue.averageSpeed=(j.queue.averageSpeed+w)/2
                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                        j.queue.averageSpeed=w
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    if(w>1000){
                                                                                        B=(w*0.001);
                                                                                        j.queue.averageSpeed=B
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    var E="KB/s";
                                                                                    if(B>0){
                                                                                        E="MB/s"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    if(a.inArray("onUploadProgress",j.settings.skipDefault)<0){
                                                                                        if(j.settings.progressData=="percentage"){
                                                                                            a("#"+x.id).find(".data").html(" - "+F+"%")
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        else{
                                                                                            if(j.settings.progressData=="speed"){
                                                                                                a("#"+x.id).find(".data").html(" - "+F+E)
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        a("#"+x.id).find(".uploadifyProgressBar").css("width",F+"%")
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    if(j.settings.onUploadProgress){
                                                                                        j.settings.onUploadProgress(x,C,z,u,j.queue.uploadSize)
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
```

Ive tried to put breakpoints near where the variable F is set.  The function only calls within the debugger when it is 0,  I thought that maybe it was because by that time the file uploaded already but also tried to put if statements within the code to only stop the debugger when bytes uploaded was greater than 100 which is not that much, but it seems like for some reason it is not being called after the 0 bytes were initiated.

I do not see any errors relating to uploadify within the console.  Please hellp!!

Comment: You don't see any error in console `Firefox Mac`?

Comment: Nothing has been coming up in regards to the upldoadify script.  I am thinking of just seperating all the code there and debugging the lines where it updates.